# Trying to do a unit test for a controller with $state

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to write some unit tests for my Angular 1.5 components based on this [tutorial](https://velesin.io/2016/08/23/unit-testing-angular-1-5-components/).

```
import notificationBannerTemplate from 'app/components/notification-banner/notification-banner.html';

const notificationBanner = {
    templateUrl: notificationBannerTemplate,
    controller: notificationBannerController,
    bindings: {
        user: '<notificationBannerUser',
        onNotificationClick: '<notificationBannerOnNotificationClick',
    },
};

notificationBanner.$inject = ['$state'];

function notificationBannerController($state) {
    const ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
        ctrl.goToProfile = goToProfile;
    };

    function goToProfile() {
        ctrl.onNotificationClick();
        $state.go('app.profile.settings');
    }
}

export default notificationBanner;
```

And my test looks like this:

```
import unitHelpers from 'test/unit/unit-helpers.js';

describe('notificationBanner component', () => {
    let parentScope;
    let element;
    let state;

    const $stateMock = {};

    beforeEach(() => {
        angular.mock.module(($provide) => {
            $provide.value('$state', $stateMock);
        });
    });
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('CustomerComponentsModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(($compile, $rootScope) => {
        parentScope = $rootScope.$new();
        state = jasmine.createSpyObj('$state', ['go']);


        parentScope.user = {
            email: 'test@test.com',
        };

        parentScope.closeBanner = function() {
        };


        element = angular.element(
            `<notification-banner
                notification-banner-user="user"
                notification-banner-on-notification-click="closeBanner">
            </notification-banner>`);
        $compile(element)(parentScope);
        parentScope.$digest();
    }));


    it('should call the goToProfile function when the button is clicked', () => {
        const componentElement = unitHelpers.findByTestId(element, 'bounced-email-banner--button');
        componentElement.click();
        expect(state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('app.profile.settings');
    });
});
```

I've tried a few different things from what I've read online, but every time I run my test I get the error `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$state.go('app.profile.settings')')`

How can I test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem --- had to add a 'go' method to my $stateMock.

```
const $stateMock = {
    go: jasmine.createSpy('go'),
};
```

Then I was able to test with `expect($stateMock.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('app.profile.settings');`

Comment: Yes, this is how it is usually done. `$stateMock` should be `let` or `var`, because a mock is supposed to be refreshed in beforeEach.